# Feasibility of Neo4j-Community edition?

Tags: java, neo4j

We are using neo4j community edition in our project for searching purpose. Recently due to Java heap memory size our database stopped responding and the running project stopped working in between.

I have some questions related to it.

1. What is the maximum size of the graph, node, relationship etc that can be created on neo4j community edition?
2. Is it feasible to use community edition in the project in production.?

Comment: The DozerDB plugin project is aimed at those who want to use Neo4j Community Edition for their production deployments.  It’s a GPL licensed bootstrapping plugin that adds features such as multi-database and enterprise constraints.   https://dozerdb.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) While there still is a theoretical limit, it's no longer practically relevant since version 3.x.

2) As always, the answer is **it depends**. Do you require high availability ? Do you require hot backups ? Do you require metrics ? Is your application mission critical ? Do you require support ? Can you comply with the community edition license for your production environment ? The list goes on and on ...

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Sir According to you there is no harm in using community edition if we don't need these extra functionality in our project. Is that so.

Comment: If you can comply with the CE license and don't need the extra functionality/performance (of the database) or extra services (that Neo Technology can deliver) ... then by all means use the CE.

Comment: Ok.Sir last question what must be the min RAM requirement

Comment: That too depends :-). Seriously, if you can have enough RAM for the full graph, you should consider doing that. Your infrastructure should focus on RAM (memory is cheap isn't it) and fast disks (SSD) before anything else.

Comment: ok sir. lll surely take it into consideration and make the required changes]

Comment: Is there any other way to connect to you for further queries in future]

Comment: Stackoverflow works but you can also join https://neo4j-users.slack.com/. Both are "watched" by Neo Technology engineers.

Comment: what is there to comply with on the community edition license? it's GPLv3

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are not aware that Neo4j Enterprise is free to use under its open source license.  You should use Neo4j Enterprise in production - you don't get production support with the open source distribution, but you do not get it with community edition either.

This link below is the site my company manages for US federal agencies who use Neo4j Enterprise open source distros in production and support it themselves, or have integrators support entire stack - not just Neo4j.

Neo4j Inc used to have them available but as you can imagine - that doesn't help sales much.

https://graphstack.io

You can learn more about the history at https://blog.igovsol.com

Comment: AGPL (the non-commercial license of Neo4j Enterprise) is risky to use in closed source projects. https://opensource.google.com/docs/using/agpl-policy/

Comment: Its no longer AGPL, as of Neo4j 5.x.x

Comment: Neo4j closed source EE far before 5.x.   If you want features such as multi-database for Neo4j Community edition, then you can use the DozerDB plugin which is vanilla GPL licensed.   https://dozerdb.org